# Raspbian. gstreamer-1.0 flips video when I play it using GPU. Videoflip gives error

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, flip, mirror

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/23869705/4073836 and it was very usefull to me.
At least I am able to play HD from my filesystem. But.
When I use software decoder

`$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./test720p3kbps.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! eglglessink`

I got normal picture on my screen while it is very slow.

Using omxplayer gives me brilliant picture. It is fast and correct.

And my own goal

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./test720p3kbps.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! eglglessink
```

also plays smooth. But it flips the picture upside-down! :'(

I've tried `omxh263dec` and `omxmjpegdec` with the same result.
`decodebin` and `playbin` did no result either.

I could use `videoflip` but it crashes my pipe as stably as AK-74 would do:

```
*** glibc detected *** gst-launch-1.0: free(): invalid pointer: 0x004aaf50 ***
Aborted
```

My gpu_mem in config.txt is set to 256

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.2.0
GStreamer 1.2.0
http://packages.qa.debian.org/gstreamer1.0
```

I've installed it via apt-get install.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The video is actually playing "correctly", it is the OpenGL coordinate system that is flipped.  
I have had success with this issue by adding a `format string` as a *work-around*.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./test720p3kbps.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! "video/x-raw, format=(string)I420"  ! eglglessink
```